# access button in tabbed activity fragment

Tags: android-studio, tabs

Sorry for bad English..Really need help here!

i just start exploring the android studio a few days ago so i still new in it.
My problem is i cant access the buttons i created in tabbed activity. im using android studio 1.5.1.Below is the final output :

[image]

as you can see, i manage to put button inside the tab but i cannot make them to do action because i dont know how to access them..i want them to poput alert dialog that i already created.

Here is all the code that i make :

akauninduk.java

```js
package com.example.asus.gorunnerapp;


import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.Button;

public class akauninduk extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    /**
     * The {@link PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_akauninduk);




        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.


        //String string = getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_akauninduk);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_akauninduk, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


    }





    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView;


            if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_akauninduk, container, false);
            } else
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_akauninduk2, container, false);


            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "PENGAGIHAN";
                case 1:
                    return "SENARAI PERMOHONAN";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the xml file that makes all the button as the image above: fragment_akauninduk.xml

```js
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.asus.gorunnerapp.akauninduk$PlaceholderFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="108dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="JPMM"
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/section_label"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="RM15,000 / RM1000"
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#2618a1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pilih Menu"
            android:id="@+id/bButton1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="108dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="NADI"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/section_label"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="RM15,000 / RM1000"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#2618a1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pilih Menu"
            android:id="@+id/bButton2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="108dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="MAYANG"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/section_label"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="RM15,000 / RM1000"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#2618a1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pilih Menu"
            android:id="@+id/bButton3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="108dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="UMNO"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/section_label"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="RM15,000 / RM1000"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#2618a1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pilih Menu"
            android:id="@+id/bButton4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i created a new java class to handle fragment_akauninduk.xml file, and i already make the function so that the button will work when clicked but i did not work.

Here is the java class that handle fragment_akauninduk.xml file:

handletab.java

```js
package com.example.asus.gorunnerapp;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Asus on 21/1/2016.
 */
public class handletab extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    Button bButton1;
    Button bButton2;
    Button bButton3;
    Button bButton4;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_akauninduk);


        bButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bButton1);
        bButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bButton2);
        bButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bButton3);
        bButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bButton4);

        bButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
        bButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
        bButton3.setOnClickListener(this);
        bButton4.setOnClickListener(this);


        final String[] option = new String[] { "Add", "View", "Change", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", "View", "Change", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, option);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Option");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),option[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                bButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bButton1);
                bButton1.setText(option[which]);
            }
        });


        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        //Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_control);
        bButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bButton1);

        bButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.


        //String string = getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_akauninduk);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_akauninduk, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void showJPMM() {
        final String[] option = new String[]{"Add", "View", "Change", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", "View", "Change", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, option);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Pilih Menu");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), option[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                bButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bButton1);
                bButton1.setText(option[which]);
            }
        });


        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        //Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_control);
        bButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bButton1);

        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bButton1:
                showJPMM();
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing right now is just inflating 2 different layout, which as a result you have no way to access and use it. What you really need to do instead is to create 2 fragments (new>fragment>fragment(blank)) and then call it in the method getItem(position) like the code below. Then you make each tab do their stuff in the fragment file.

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if(position == 0){
                 FragmentPengagihan fragmentPengagihan = new FragmentPengagihan();
                 return fragmentPengagihan;
                 }

            else if(position == 1){
                 FragmentSenaraiPermohonan fragmentPermohonan = new FragmentSenaraiPermohonan();
                 return fragmentSenaraiPermohonan;
            }

            return null;
        }
```